# WPF Reading / writing JSON vs XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, wpf, data-structures

I'm looking for a solution to read and write data from a file. The data is a list composing of a file path, name and a list of compatible video formats for video playback applications on the system.
The XML data structure looks like this.

```
<player>
    <name>WMP</name>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe</path>
    <extensionList>
        <string>AVI</string>
        <string>WMP</string>
    </extensionList>
</player>
```

I have previously used a XMLSerializer to serialize a list of player classes which worked quite nicely and before that I had used SQL. I have recently heard of JSON and would like to broaden my options when it comes to storing data. Does anyone have any suggestions on which format is more suitable for my WPF application or if there are any better methods for data access that suites my needs.

Comment: JSON is usually much smaller than XML - but it also sometimes not as readable. If the user is never going to be reading your XML files, then I'd go with JSON just for the file sizes. You may want to take a look at the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I would **highly** recommend you instead go with [Json.NET by Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If you need to know datatypes and what not in your files, then XML would be the way to go.

Comment: @MightyLampshade I think im going to go with XML purely for the readability of it since the sizes really are not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoreretical advantage of XML is that you can have some sort of querying using xpath and potentionally work with larger sets of data.

Specifically in WPF you have XmlDataProvider, where you can databind your UI controls directly to xml nodes.

That's theory. In real world, you will almost for sure deserialize your xml to data transfer objects, so you can take advantage of strongly typed classes, compile time checking, OOP, etc. In this case, the mentioned advantages of xml are irrelavant.

On the other hand, JSON files are slightly smaller and JSON serializers slightly faster and probably better human readable.

File size plays role in web scenarios, where you need to transfer data betweer client and server (it's not coincidendce that JSON format comes from javascript), but it isn't your case. You probably dont have to care about serialization performance, unless you are working with large data sets.

Neither JSON nor XML is better or worse in your case. Both will do the job well and you can't make wrong decision.

Imho, if you have previously been working with XML, go for JSON now, so you will have experience with both and you will learn something new. At the end, it's just few line of code and you can easily change the serialization logic to something else when needed.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you only want to store and consume the data in your application and do not want to exchange it with another application.

JSON as a format has a very low overhead resulting in smaller files - that's why it is often used in mobile scenarios. Also, as its name "JavaScript Object Notation" also expresses, it can be handled very well with JavaScript making it a good choice for web applications.

As it has been widely used in the past years there are good libraries for .NET that can serialize .NET POCOs to JSON, e.g. [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

In your case it is more or less up to your personal choice. Based upon the requirements you describe, I don't see a strong reason to use JSON instead of XML Serialization.

Answer (score 1):

As other answered if you need your files to be smaller (in a mobile/web app for example) JSON is  the way to go, because the files are smaller.

On the other hand if the file sizes are not an issue then I would use XML, because if the files are volatile and will change their form a lot(in the case you will do more than video playback application) it will be difficult to serialize all those xml files. And here comes LINQ to XML. You should read about this, even if you do not use it in this application. LINQ is very useful in all it's forms from LINQ to SQL to LINQ to XML.

Read from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the Linq Links... I have some experience using it and absolutely see its uses for me.

Answer (score 0):

JSON and XML are doing the same thing : representing data as text.
JSON is less verbose than XML so your files will be lighter.
Parsing JSON is faster than parsing XML.

You can check [this lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to parse JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the link to NuGet, was looking for a free alternative to Json.Net.